# Can I copy the exact text of a function input?

Tags: python, string, function, input, format

I've been asked to create a function that converts an input into a board-like display for a Candy Crush-esque game, and everything seems to work except for a hidden test case. The way it works is as such:

The function should be defined as:
`def pretty_print(board):`
Where board is formatted like `[['A']*3]*4`, where A is the chosen character for display, the 3 referencing columns and the 4 referencing rows.
I'm assuming the hidden test is testing input cases where either the row or column is a 0 to see if it will correctly format, but the input board when this occurs will either return like:

When `board = [['A']*0]*4`:
Returns `[[], [], [], []]`

or when `board = [['A']*4]*0`:
Returns `[]`

I want to try and create an exact string copy of the input 'board' such as:

`string = str(board)`->
`string = "[['A']*0]*4"`, such that I may perform operations that will not result in error for these cases.

My issues is that the input always immediately formats and I'm not sure if there's a method to get around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rewriting your function to take arguments corresponding to the things you want to check.

In your case:

```py
def pretty_print(char, columns, rows):
    board = [[char] * columns] * rows
```

Then you can ensure that the various parameters are what you want.

If for some reason you *need* to check it in that string format (I highly doubt this is the correct/best way), then you could simply do:

```py
def pretty_print(char, columns, rows):
    board = [[char] * columns] * rows
    board_str = f'[[{char}] * {columns}] * {rows}'
```

and check board_str.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can change the arguments from simply 'board' due to the paramaters of the assignment, but your solution makes a lot of sense. Would there be no way to do it otherwise?

Comment: I think it really depends on what you need to test for.

You could probably reverse-engineer the string, though if it's the zero-cases as you suggest you won't be able to retrieve the character information.